# How do I delete a row from the table that has the primary key used as foreign key in my other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a foreign key relationship between two tables in my SQL Server 2008 database. When I try to delete a row from the table containing the primary key there is an error. How do I delete a row from the table that has the primary key used as foreign key in my other table?

Comment: Please share your table structure, the SQL you are trying to run and the exact error. Without some more details it's pretty difficult to help you.

Answer (score 4):

This is the point of having a foreign key constraint: You can't delete records from one table that have records referencing them from the other table.

You can use the `on delete cascade` option on the constraint itself (you will need to drop and re-create it) or first delete the referencing records from the child table and only then delete the record from the parent table.

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. Re-create the table with cascade delete as an option. More details here:
   http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

   The syntax:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE **child_table**
   (
       column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
       column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
       ...

       CONSTRAINT fk_name
       FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
       REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
          [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ] 
   );
   ```
2. Manually find the child elements where the primary key is used and delete:

   ```
   DELETE FROM table_name_with_foreign_key
   WHERE some_column=some_value;
   ```

   Then go back to the main table with the primary key and delete the row:

   ```
   DELETE FROM table_name
   WHERE some_column = some_value;
   ```

Comment: @marc_s I saw there was an edit but am not sure what was changed; is there anything I should modify in this response? Edit: please disregard, I see the formatting was altered, thank you.